# Passing the parameters to a callback function : Scope issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

I have this `someFunction` in the the view of a backbone app. Now I want to send parameters defined in this function to a callback function of jConform function. I cannot figure out how scope works in such cases.

```
someFunction: function() {
    var thisView = this,
        paramA = 10,
        paramB = $(ev.currentTarget).data("id"),
        paramC = this.getConfig(paramB);

    jConfirm(paramC.jConfirmMessage, "Confirm Deactivation", function (ans) {
                        return thisView.anotherFunction(ans, paramC);
                    });
}


anotherFunction: function(ans, paramC){
    ...
}
```

How can access the paramC from `sumeFunction` into  `anotherFunction` ?

Thanks. !

Comment: either `paramC` has to be defined outside `someFunction` or you need to call `anotherFunction` from `someFunction` passing the variable

Comment: Where / how / when is `anotherFunction` called?

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry. My mistake. Updated.

Comment: The code you have now should work as expected. `paramC` is passed to `thisView.anotherFunction`. JavaScript has lexical scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unsure about: if `paramC` is available in - `return thisView.anotherFunction(ans, thisView.paramC)`.

Then answer is -  Yes, `paramC` is available in that statement.

Reason - the callback function defined here remembers the environment in which it was created. This idea is similar to closure. Read about closure and lexical scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

But if your question is about how to access `paramC` inside the body of `anotherFunction` method, then you can do what as described in the first answer. Or you can create a new property of view object and assign `paramC`  to it.

And one last thing - javascript has functional scope. you can read about javascript scopes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
someFunction: function() {
//private
    var that = this;
    jConfirm(paramC.jConfirmMessage, "Confirm Deactivation", function (ans) {
                        return thisView.deactivateConfirm(ans, paramC);
                    });
    return {
//public 
        thisView : that,
        paramA : 10,
        paramB : $(ev.currentTarget).data("id"),
        paramC : that.getConfig(paramB)
    };
}

anotherFunction: function(ans, paramC){
  //use it here
}

anotherFunction(ans, someFunction.paramC);
```

Useful links
[first link](http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/)
[second link](http://advjavascripts.blogspot.in/2014/08/javascript-scoping-and-hoisting.html)

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

to expose inner functions and variables you need to return something from the first function. Its good that you wrap them in a return statement.

```
someFunction: function() {
    var thisView = this;

    thisView.paramA = 10;
    thisView.paramB = $(ev.currentTarget).data("id");
    thisView.paramC = this.getConfig(paramB);

    return {
        paramA : thisView.paramA,
        paramB : thisView.paramB,
        paramC : thisView.paramC,
        jConfirm: function(thisView.paramC.jConfirmMessage, "Confirm Deactivation", function (ans)) {
                        return thisView.anotherFunction(ans, thisView.paramC)
        }
    }     
}


anotherFunction: function(ans, paramC){
    console.log(someFunction.paramC);
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely helpful.